# Edit .realm file by Realm Studio not working

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a default.realm with existing data and tables. When I opened default.realm file by Realm Studio and add some records.

But when finish editing the .realm file does not change modified date and seems like no updated data.

Can anybody help me to check why ? Is this a bug of Realm Studio ?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I've just tried adding a new Person object to my Realm and it worked, so, eh. If you explicitly begin the transaction, don't forget to also commit.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Windows 8.1 pro